# Adding points to the user when completing a quiz in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So the title is pretty describable. I have currently setup a database and coded a simple quiz script where a user would be able to answer a couple of questions then submit the answers.

The questions are given by levels. Say for example, at level 1, if the user answers correctly, he/she shall proceed to level 2.

The profile of the user and the quiz part have been already provided. I was just wondering if there's any way I could implement a point system so that whenever the user answers a question, he/she will have points added to their profile and so on.

I'd like to only know the method/idea on how to go about this. Any resources, tips, advices, help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question risks being closed as "too general", but here's a general answer: create a `Points` table with a primary key (for example an autoincrement value), a user identifier, a quiz identifier, the current timestamp, the number of points awarded, and optionally the reason for awarding the points. Insert into the table whenever you're awarding points. To report the points, just `SUM` for the user.

Comment: Your users can take quiz after login?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the questions and answers are stored in some relational DB you could have a column which stores how many points that question/answer is worth.

Then in your users table you could have a column which contains a column for an accumulative total all the questions they have answered correctly.

The downside to that is it will be impossible to know where they got the points from. If that is an issue you would need another table which would store the user id and question id so that the score can be retrieved from the question/answer table.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the method that you want . When ever user's score is updated , you will send a ajax request to the server that will update the score in the database table. (  Hoping you are familiar with ajax) you could implement something like say , /api/v1/user-id/new-score , which will update the score of the user user-id with new-score     ( with necessary security measures like , say api-key)